# Cut region out of intersecting lines on Android canvas

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android canvas on which I'm drawing a series of lines to represent a hexagonal game board. The hexagon is subdivided with several intersecting interior lines.

I'm trying to figure out how to "cut out" a smaller hexagon from the center of the main hexagon, similar to this image: http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~pbv/stuff/hstzaar/hstzaar.png.

Is it possible to position a polygon over the intersecting lines and take the "difference" of the shapes, such that the lines underneath are modified to end at the polygon edges?

It might be sufficient to simply place an opaque polygon on top of the board center, but I was curious if it was possible to actually modify the underlying lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are only 3 interior lines that run through the center of the hexagon, it's actually easier to draw each of them in two segments rather than try to cut them out later.

I'd still be interested to know if my original question was possible, but I solved the problem for now.